# php include .phar file not working

Tags: php, apache, osticket

Im using os-ticket support script and have trouble in special line.

```
$this->cache_translations = include $this->STREAM;
```

this line will include a .phar file.

something like this: `phar:///dir/to/fa.phar/x.mo`

php is not throwing any error but i get white page.
I test this code in a single php file and still get nothing.

btw this script is `working` in PHP Version 5.4.45
and my current version is 5.5.37.

thanks in advance

Comment: Did you enable all warnings and errors?

Comment: @Eiko yes i do. every thing is on.

Comment: If You try `file_get_contents('phar:///dir/to/fa.phar')`, does it read the file contents correctly? Just to figure out if You have access to the phar file at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using suhosin to secure your php installation, you need to add this setting in your php.ini file under [suhosin]

```
suhosin.executor.include.whitelist = phar
```